# Combination of classification and regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression

The dataset I am working with contains the readings of an 8-sensors gas-sensor-array. The response of a sensor depends on the gas stimuli (methane, ethylene, etc.) and the concentration of the gas (20 ppm, 50 ppm, etc.). The dataset consists of 640 examples and each example is of shape=(6000,8) since there are 8 sensors on the array.
[(sensor-array response to 100ppm of Methane)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3Umz.png)

My task is to make a model that will predict the class of the sensor-array reading (from which gas this reading is) and after that, I want to predict the concentration of that gas.

So far I have built a classification model based on 1D convolutional layers which successfully classifies examples into four categories (gases) with 98% accuracy.

How could I predict the concentration value of the gas? Is it possible to perform a regression analysis on the classified examples or should I look for a whole different approach?

Comment: Do you have any prior insight on the way sensors behave depending on the concentration?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you mean, but all I have is 640 "fingerprints" and for each of them I do know the concentration of the gas. The dataset is freely available at https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Twin+gas+sensor+arrays

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: @desertnaut In that case, maybe it should be migrated to https://ai.stackexchange.com rather than closed?

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a 1 input and 2 output neural network? One output for classification and another for regression ?

Comment: @AdarshWase Yes. My initial thought was to train four regressors that will be trained on the data for each one of the gas categories. But now I am thinking if there is a more compact way to solve this problem in only one network which will output both the classification and the regression result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this task, I would just make a multi output neural network like this:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

inp = Input(shape=(n_features,))
hidden1 = Dense(20, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inp)
hidden2 = Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(hidden1)

out_reg = Dense(1, activation='linear')(hidden2)
out_class = Dense(n_class, activation='softmax')(hidden2)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=[out_reg, out_class])
model.compile(loss=['mse','sparse_categorical_crossentropy'], optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, [y_train_reg, y_train_class], epochs=150, batch_size=32, verbose=2)
```

One output for regression and another for classification. Below is the image of neural network architecture:

[image]

If you don't know how to create such networks, please read the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional).

Comment: This is the better answer of the two.  But I'm leaving mine up for now because you also need to edit the loss function.

Comment: Adding loss weighs is a good idea if the scale of the two loss functions is very different